# SCOPE_IDENTITY() multiple insert

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

How can I avoid these type can I capture value for each identity insert and insert in other table

```
Insert into LookupTables (a, b, c, d, e, OtherInfo, SortOrder)
Values (a, b, c, d, e, NULL, NULL)

DECLARE @LookupID INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 

Insert into LookupTables (a, b, c, d, e, OtherInfo, SortOrder)
Values (a, b, c, d, e, @LookupID, NULL)

Insert into LookupTables (a, b, c, d, e, OtherInfo, SortOrder)
Values (a, b, c, d, e, NULL, NULL)

DECLARE @LookupID2 INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 

Insert into LookupTables (a, b, c, d, e, OtherInfo, SortOrder)
Values (a, b, c, d, e, @LookupID2, NULL)
```

Comment: I don't understand the question here. What is the problem or what are you trying to do? You could skip declaring the variables and just put SCOPE_IDENTITY() as the column value.

Comment: i am getting the identity value from first and inserting the identity into 2nd statement within the same table.rather than declaring for each time can i get value so that i can insert for multiple records

Comment: No, there is no "magic" way to do this - what you're doing is perfectly fine, and it **IS** the way to go ..

Comment: As long as you want to keep using "raw" low-level SQL, this is about as good as it gets. You'd get a massive productivity boost from using an **ORM** (object-relational mapper) which would *also* save you from a lot of this boring, error-prone "glue" code you need to write manually right now.

Comment: To add to Frisbee's answer: You can use an [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause to get any data from the rows (Note plural.), e.g. identity column values for newly inserted rows.  `OUTPUT` can be used with `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `MERGE` and provides access to both _before_ and _after_ values in the case of `UPDATE`.  A tool well worth having in your pocket.

Answer (score 1):

If sort order is unique (and I suspect it is)

Then insert all with values (), (), () and use an [output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause

I do exactly this but I don't have time right now to look up the code

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @t table 
(
    id  int not null identity,
    a   int ,
    b   int ,
    c   int ,
    OtherInfo int
);


insert into @t (a, b, c)
output inserted.a, inserted.b, inserted.c, inserted.id 
into LookupTables (a, b, c, OtherInfo)
values (1,1,1),(2,2,2),(3,3,3),(4,4,4),(5,5,5);

select * from @t;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51555/3)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how you can do this without declaring variables for each last inserted identity value. Of course you could actually just reuse a single variable. But even easier would be to skip the variable entirely.

```
Insert into LookupTables (a, b, c, d, e, OtherInfo, SortOrder)
Values (a, b, c, d, e, NULL, NULL)

Insert into LookupTables (a, b, c, d, e, OtherInfo, SortOrder)
Values (a, b, c, d, e, SCOPE_IDENTITY(), NULL)

Insert into LookupTables (a, b, c, d, e, OtherInfo, SortOrder)
Values (a, b, c, d, e, NULL, NULL)

Insert into LookupTables (a, b, c, d, e, OtherInfo, SortOrder)
Values (a, b, c, d, e, SCOPE_IDENTITY(), NULL)
```

Comment: How much simpler could it be? You have 4 separate inserts right? Not sure what else could be done to make it "simpler"